# Jython debugging in Eclipse with PyDev raises RuntimeError: cannot join current thread

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jython, pydev, sikuli

i'm developing some Sikuli scripts, which have to be done in jython. I managed successfully to run jython in eclipse IDE, but when i wan't to debug scripts i have a problem.

The eclipse pydev debugger runs the whole script, but then after executing the whole code properly it raises errors after the last line is executed. This is very annoying, because it prevents me from debugging nested scripts.

For example, the following code runs smoothly:

```html
print("test")
```

in debug it prints "test" but immediately afterwards it rises:

```html
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nrblck/jython/Lib/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/home/nrblck/jython/Lib/threading.py", line 297, in _MainThread__exitfunc
    t.join()
  File "/home/nrblck/jython/Lib/threading.py", line 128, in join
    raise RuntimeError("cannot join current thread")
RuntimeError: cannot join current thread
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nrblck/jython/Lib/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/home/nrblck/jython/Lib/threading.py", line 297, in _MainThread__exitfunc
    t.join()
  File "/home/nrblck/jython/Lib/threading.py", line 128, in join
    raise RuntimeError("cannot join current thread")
RuntimeError: cannot join current thread
```

The lines 126-128 of threading.py are

```html
126        def join(self, timeout=None):
127            if self._thread == java.lang.Thread.currentThread():
128                raise RuntimeError("cannot join current thread")
```

I have installed jython 2.7.0 (newest stable) in home/nrblck/jython
I have tried all debug options, JDK enviorments and multiple jython versions. 
The OS is Xubuntu , which is basically Ubuntu without any fireworks. Im running it on virtualbox if that matters - i changed number of CPUs dedicated to that system from 8 to 1 and it didn't solve the problem.

How to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

reinstalling eclipse and defining python path in eclipse for this project from scratch solved this problem.